# Ruby - PayPal instant update callback API for updating shipping rates

Tags: paypal

When the user changes their address on PayPal, PayPal makes an AJAX call to your server for new shipping rates. Our server gets the request from PayPal. I have this working. 
My dilemma is ‘how do I’ and ‘where do I’ send back the new shipping rates to PayPal? The API does not say how to send it back. In a POST? In a GET? In a Render? 
I have tried a render :text and sent it in a string 
“METHOD=CallbackResponseOFFERINSURANCEOPTION=falseL_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME0=UPS AirL_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL0=UPS Next Day Air FreightL_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT0=20.00&L_TAXAMT0=2.20&L_INSURANCEAMOUNT0=1.51L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT0=true”
I have tried to render an xml.builder. 
I am using the Active Merchant Gem which does not have a method for the shipping rates callback.
When I try to create a similar method to send to the sandbox PayPal URL, the token and the CorrelationID changes.

Answer (score 0):

When using the callback API you're acting as a web service, so you simply need to make sure your script outputs the NVP response like the sample you've shown.

You can make calls to your shipping carrier API's, etc, and for this you would be making POST calls, but then once you've compiled that data you'll simply generate the NVP string and echo it out to the screen.

You want nothing but that NVP string to be output when you run that script, just like what you receive back when working with NVP web services and POSTing a request to it.  You're just on the other end, so you're generating that NVP response.

I will say, though, that in my experience the callback system isn't very reliable.  The highest amount of time you can set it to is 6 seconds, and that just isn't enough to receive the data from PayPal, hit 3rd party API's, generate the result and send it back to PayPal. It really only works with very simplistic shipping services.  Otherwise, it winds up timing out and defaults to your shipping options sent with SetExpressCheckout.

Hope this useful.